# Is $V$ a vector space under these operations?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $$V=\{x \in \mathbb{R} : x>0\}$$

For $x,y,a \in \Bbb{R}$, define $x\oplus y=xy$ and $x\odot a=x^a$. Is $V$ a vector space under these operations? Justify your answer.

Comment: I've edited your question to include MathJax, and fixed some apparent typos. Please verify that it's correct. Also, can you share your thoughts on the problem and explain what you've tried?

Comment: There exists a "MO duplicate" (which was, of course, closed): http://mathoverflow.net/questions/144608/is-v-a-vector-space-under-these-operation-justify-your-answer

Comment: It is not clear whether in your definition of $x\odot a$ the real number $x$ is considered as a scalar and $a$ as a vector, or otherwise. (If you look at the two answers posted so far, one of the posters understood this one way, the other one understood this the other way.)

Answer (score 5):

Define $\phi:V \to \mathbb{R}$ by $\phi(v) = \log v$. Note that $\phi$ is bijective.

We see that $\phi( x\oplus y) = \phi(xy)=\log x + \log y = \phi(x)+\phi(y)$, and $\phi( x \odot a) =\log(x^a) = a \log x = a \phi(x)$.

Since $(\mathbb{R}, +,\cdot)$ is a vector space, it follows that $(V,\oplus, \odot)$ is a vector space.

Answer (score 3):

To be a vector space, you must first check that it satisfies the abelian group axioms: For all $x,y,z\in V$:

- $x\oplus y\in V$
- $x\oplus y=y\oplus x$
- $(x\oplus y)\oplus z=x\oplus (y\oplus z)$
- There is an element $e\in V$ such that $x\oplus e=x$
- $x\oplus x^*=e$ for some $x^*\in V$

Furthermore, it must "play nicely" with the underlying field (in this case, $\mathbb{R}$). Rigorously, this means satisfying all of these axioms, for all $x,y\in V$ and all $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$:

- $x\odot a\in V$
- $x\odot 1=x$
- $x\odot (ab) = (x\odot a)\odot b$
- $(x+y)\odot a = (x\odot a)+(y\odot b)$
- $x\odot(a+b) = (x\odot a)+(x\odot b)$

where $+$ is the usual addition.

To *not* be a vector space, all you need is one set of $x,y,z,a,b$ that fails just one of these axioms (or a proof that no such $e$ can exist). So if one of them seems unlikely to you, you might start by looking at simple examples to see if they hold up.

Answer (score 0):

It's not hard to verify $\oplus$ and $\odot$ are closed operations. Now $\langle V,\oplus\rangle$ is associative, commutative, has an identity $1$, and inverse is possible $x^{-1}$ (we say it's an Abelian group). For $\langle V,\odot\rangle$, it satisfies two distributive laws, $(x^b)^a=x^{ab}$, and $x^1=x$. Hence, $\langle V,\mathbb{R},\oplus,\odot\rangle$ satisfies the definition of a vector space.